# automatic and dynamic countdown timer android

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I want to make a countdown timer that is automatically triggered by time.
Let's say for example the countdown should automatically start at 12:00:00 AM and ends at 11:59:59 PM. The problem is if ever the fragment will be destoyed or the application is terminated, how will my countdown timer automatically counts the time left before the timer ends when the view is created again?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the start time.  Just define the end time.

Whenever your fragment that shows the countdown is displayed, compute the timer display based on the difference between the current time and the end time.

When the fragment becomes invisible, you don't have to do anything because the end time stays the same.  Just worry about updating the timer display when the fragment is visible.

Comment: how to calculate the difference between the current and the end? I'm using SntpClient to get current time and it's returning a long value.

Comment: Subtract the end time from the start time.  I thought that would have been obvious?